# angular проблема с регистрацией модуля или компонента немогу понять

Tags: angularjs, angular2, angular

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]выдает ошибку, немогу разобраться в чем проблема

compiler.js:2427 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-todo-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-todo-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-todo-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
[ERROR ->]
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:0

код основного модуля

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import {TodoListModule} from "./todo-list/todo-list.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    TodoListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

код подключаемого модуля

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

import {TodoListComponent} from "./todo-list.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TodoListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})

export class TodoListModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо архитектура хромает. По идее всё сделано правильно и `TodoListComponent` должен находиться в `declarations` в `TodoListModule`. В твоём случае нужно просто добавить `TodoListComponent` в `AppModule`.

Comment: когда добавляю в AppModule все работает, но мне же как то нужно модули разбить по компонентам чтобы в одном модуле каши небыло=)

Comment: @Чайник значит ты используешь этот компонент в темплейте главного модуля, а не дочернего. Ищи ошибку

Comment: модуль же нужно только в главном модели регистрировать? компоненты с дочернего модуля невидно вообще нигде почему то

Comment: @Чайник если ты всё сделал правильно, то должно получиться вот что: у тебя в app.component.html есть router-outlet это раз, в app-routing.module.ts у тебя есть роут { path: 'todo', loadchilder: 'путь_к_твоему_модулю' } это два, и в app.module.ts ты импортируешь app-routing.module

Comment: роутов пока нет в app.component.html  у меня только такой код <app-header></app-header>
<app-todo-list></app-todo-list> и на app-todo-list выдает эту ошибку, в главный вопрос загрузил скрин файловой структуры, может там что не так?

Comment: @Чайник ну так модули используют, чтобы lazy-load модули делать, а для этого нужен роутинг. В твоём коде `app-todo-list` находится в главном модуле, поэтому компилятор ругается.

Comment: то есть если у меня в приложении в принципе только одна страница но много компонентов мне вообще дополнительные модули не нужны? (то есть мне роуты даже некуда делать )

Comment: @Чайник я кажется тебя понял. Добавь `TodoListComponent` в `exports` в `TodoListModule`

Comment: Вот это сработало на пятерку=) Благодарю за помощ, возможно не совсем понятно объяснил задачу, еще не до конца разобрался в ангуляре=)

Comment: @Чайник экспортировать из другого модуля нужно все `declarations` и `imports`, так как главному модулю нужно как-то получить доступ. Но с роутингом такого делать уже не надо.